# how to check the path in web service

Tags: cxf, ibatis

I m using cxf webservices.I have a service path @Path'/summary/abc/{xyz}/name/{login}'.

I want to generate some custom error message when someone give wrong url like

'/summary/ab/{xyz}/na/{login}/'

Comment: Ask a specific question, or clarify what you mean. Nobody can answer your question as it currently stands.

Answer (score 0):

This email has the recipe: http://osdir.com/ml/users-cxf-apache/2009-06/msg00528.html.